# How to zip a folder in my Win32 Visual C++ app using a system call

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, zip, system, call

I am trying to zip a folder in my Win32 Visual C++ app using a system call. On my computer, I can do this by the cmd command:

```
PowerShell -Command "Compress-Archive -Path  C:\Users\ttyler\Desktop\Software\Folder2\RUN -DestinationPath C:\Users\ttyler\Desktop\Software\Folder2\RUN"
```

Where "Try" is a folder.

I am trying to do this on my app using a System call, but in my app, I have the "Path" and the "DestinationPath" stored in variables (because the destination path is being pulled in by the user). I'm not sure I'm using the variables correctly in my system call because this is giving me the error: "'+': cannot add two pointers" and "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type".

```
TCHAR path = L"C:\Users\ttyler\Desktop\Software\Folder2\RUN";
TCHAR DestinationPath = L"C:\Users\ttyler\Desktop\Software\Folder2\RUN.zip";
system("Compress-Archive -Path" + path[0] + "-DestinationPath" + DestinationPath[0]);
```

What am I doing wrong when using the variables in my system call?

Comment: `system()` runs an instance of `cmd.exe /C <command-line>` where `<command-line>` is the specified parameter. `PowerShell.exe` is a separate app with its own command-line parameters. `PowerShell.exe` commands are not `cmd.exe` commands.  Use `CreateProcess()` instead run `PowerShell.exe` directly.  Otherwise, put the PowerShell commands into a `.bat` script, and then use `system()` to run that script.

Comment: I did: 'STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't work for many reasons:

- you are trying to assign wide string literals to single-char variables.  You need to use arrays or pointers instead, eg:

```c
TCHAR path[] = L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\RUN";
TCHAR DestinationPath[] = L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\RUN.zip";
```

```c
LPCTSTR path = L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\RUN";
LPCTSTR DestinationPath = L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\RUN.zip";
```

- you cannot concatenate string literals with array/single-chars the way you are trying to do.  You will have to allocate new arrays and copy/format the various substrings into it, eg:

```c
WCHAR path[] = L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\RUN";
WCHAR DestinationPath[] = L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\RUN.zip";

WCHAR cmd[(MAX_PATH*2)+50] = {};
swprintf(cmd, L"Compress-Archive -Path \"%s\" -DestinationPath \"%s\"", path, DestinationPath);

// use cmd as needed...
```

Or, just use `std::wstring` instead, eg:

```c
std::wstring path = L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\RUN";
std::wstring DestinationPath = L"C:\\Users\\ttyler\\Desktop\\Software\\Folder2\\RUN.zip";

std::wstring cmd = L"Compress-Archive -Path \"" + path + L"\" -DestinationPath \"" + DestinationPath + L"\"";

// use cmd as needed...
```

- `system()` takes a `const char*` pointer as input.  But you are using `TCHAR` strings, which will only work correctly for your wide string literals if `TCHAR` is `WCHAR`.  Which means you can't pass your concatenated string to `system()` anyway.  You will have to use `_wsystem()` instead, eg:

```cpp
_wsystem(cmd); // when using WCHAR[]/LPWSTR
```

```cpp
_wsystem(cmd.c_str()); // when using std::wstring
```

- `system()`/`_wsystem()` runs an instance of `cmd.exe /C <command-line>`, where `<command-line>` is the specified input string. But [`PowerShell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/powershell) is its own app with its own command-line parameters. `PowerShell.exe` commands ARE NOT valid `cmd.exe` commands, ie you are trying to execute this:

```
cmd.exe /C Compress-Archive -Path <path> -DestinationPath <dest>
```

Which is not a valid command, as `cmd.exe` does not know what `Compress-Archive` is.  You would need to execute this instead:

```
cmd.exe /C PowerShell -Command "Compress-Archive -Path \"<path>\" -DestinationPath \"<dest>\""
```

```cpp
WCHAR cmd[(MAX_PATH*2)+70] = {};
swprintf(cmd, L"PowerShell -Command \"Compress-Archive -Path \\\"%s\\\" -DestinationPath \\\"%s\\\"", path, DestinationPath);
```

```cpp
std::wstring cmd = L"PowerShell -Command \"Compress-Archive -Path \\\"" + path + L"\\\" -DestinationPath \\\"" + DestinationPath + L"\\\"";
```

But, you really should use [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) instead to run `PowerShell.exe` directly, don't use `cmd.exe` at all, eg:

```cpp
STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(STARTUPINFO), 0};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd/*cmd.data()*/, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

Otherwise, put your PowerShell commands into a `.bat` script, eg:

```
@echo off
PowerShell -Command "Compress-Archive -Path \"%0\" -DestinationPath \"%1\""
```

And then you can use `system()`/`_wsystem()` to run that script, eg:

```cpp
WCHAR cmd[(MAX_PATH*2)+25] = {};
swprintf(cmd, L"myscript.bat \"%s\" \"%s\"", path, DestinationPath);
_wsystem(cmd);
```

```cpp
std::wstring cmd = L"myscript.bat \"" + path + L"\" \"" + DestinationPath + L"\"";
_wsystem(cmd.c_str());
```

Comment: If using Create Process, what would 'si' and 'pi' be? Are these the path and destination path? Also, if putting the PowerShell commands into a .bat script, should the .bat script be saved in the project directory?

Comment: @Alyssa I showed you exactly what `si` and `pi` are. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw).